# Convolution in frequency domain, what is the output bandwidth

Tags: convolution

If two signals do convolution in frequency domain, would the output width/BW be related to the width/BW input signals?
Would it be addition or any other?

Answer (score 4):

Following a time-domain convolution analysis which relates the output signal's domain of support to the input signals' domain of supports, we could reach a similar conclusion:

Given two frequency domain signals with domain of supports (for positive frequencies) such that $X(\omega) \neq 0$ for $\omega_1 < \omega < \omega_2$ and $H(\omega) \neq 0$ for $\omega_3 < \omega < \omega_4$, then their convolution $Y(\omega) = X(\omega) \star H(\omega)$ will have the domain of support as $Y(\omega) \neq 0$ for $$ \omega_1 + \omega_3 < \omega < \omega_2 + \omega_4 $$

Therefore the bandwidth of $Y(\omega)$ is related to the bandwidths of $X(\omega)$ and $H(\omega)$ as:

$$ BW_Y =  (\omega_2 + \omega_4) - (\omega_1 + \omega_3) $$
$$ BW_Y =  (\omega_4 - \omega_3) + (\omega_2 - \omega_1) $$
$$ BW_Y =  BW_H + BW_X $$

This assumes that the domains were **compact** and **finite**. If they are either noncompact or non-finite the result should be modified accordingly.

Comment: Nice answer, but great if you change the Y(omega) to H(omega) in " Therefore the bandwidth of Y(omega) is related to the bandwidths of X(omega) and Y(omega)"